# Window focus when editing remote files over FTP on a Mac

Tags: ftp, macos, focus

I use a combination of ForkLift and Textmate to edit files on a remote server via FTP. it works really well, except for one little quirk: when I hit save on Textmate, Forklift saves the file, and then Forklift takes the focus. So, every time I hit Save on Textmate, I have to wait for Forklift to save, and then hit Cmd + Tab to return to Textmate.

Is there a way this can be avoided? I.e. is there a way that when I hit Save on TextMate, the focus does NOT get taken by ForkLift?

And, by the way, I tried to edit the files with TextEdit instead of TextMate, and the behaviour did not change. So, I'm guessing this is either a ForkLift issue, or a Mac issue.

Either way, help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested with Forklift Version 2.0.6 (315) and couldn't find the behavior described by you. The focus wasn't lost by saving the document within Textmate.
Maybe 'already' fixed?